# When should the message informing the user that the password they entered is wrong go away?

Tags: login, html, error-message, messages

This is a follow up to [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38639/what-to-present-when-wrong-log-in-information-entered) since it got closed. In a log in form, after the user enters the wrong password, when should the message saying "wrong password or user name" go away? For example should it go away after the first character of the  password is typed? This is assuming the message is in plain text beneath the password field (not an alert window or anything like that).

Answer (score 9):

Error messages shouldn't go away on their own unless

- Errors were resolved by User's Input
- User wanted those error messages to be hidden by clicking a X which an error message may have.

If error message is displayed and user makes the same mistake which produces the same error message for the second time, the error message can blink or have a brief color transition which indicates that the error has appear all over again.

Answer (score -4):

it's literally up to you. Most of the time developers actually leave it as is.

Comment: While I agree with leaving it in place, do you have any reasons for this?

Comment: If it wasn't for Brendon's comment I wouldn't have understood what is meant by "leave it as is".