# How to show user login password is wrong after the first time e.g. flash "wrong password" message

Tags: login, error-message, password

This is a follow up to [this question](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/38782/when-should-the-message-informing-the-user-that-the-password-they-entered-is-wro) asking about what should be displayed when a user enters a wrong password.

Here is my current design: when logging into a website if the user enters a wrong username/password, the page displays beneath the password field "wrong username/password" in red. The conses of the linked to question was to keep the "wrong username/password" message there, which I'm fine with. What I'm concerned about is what will happen if the user enters a wrong password again? I don't want the message to blink and I'm not sure how to show the user that the second password is also wrong and it's not just the page is hanging. If it changes colour I was thinking of changing it to yellow for 0.25 seconds. If this is the approach should the first time the message is displayed the colour is different initially or does the colour only change after the first wrong login?

EDIT: I forgot to mention the password field is cleared if it wrong. I'm not sure if this enough of an indicator though, is it?

Comment: Go for simplicity - nothing beats actually **telling** the user. Anything fancier is not discoverable or leads to frustration.

Comment: @DeerHunter so you are recommending an alert window?

Comment: **If you clear the password field if only the password is wrong, you have a security problem on your hands - actually you are willingly informing the attacker that he can try another password and that his chosen username is correct.**

Comment: A simple red line of text in the same window will do. After all, most users will not see it, thus you may be overdesigning your site.

Comment: @DeerHunter no you are quit wrong. If I always clear the password field and leave the user field this doesn't tell the attacker anything. If I only left the user field if the username existed then it may.

Comment: I feel much better now, thanks a bunch. You may want to edit the title to reflect that, though (I was driven to your post because the title exhibited a security flaw).

Comment: @DeerHunter sorry but it's been too long to edit the comment. There was another question whose answers I was following which said to clear the password and leave the user name.

Comment: Why not simply display a message indicating the number of the attempt. IE "incorrect username / password combination" in combination with a "this will be your n-th attempt to login" near the login/submit button.

Answer (score 5):

I would not go with a different color since it implies it is not the previous error (wrong password) but a new error this time around.

A couple approaches you can take:

- Animate the password input field to **shake/vibrate** when the wrong password is entered (eg: mac login window)
- **Remove the password** if it is incorrect and highlight the field and show the error message
- **Reload the page** and display the error message

Comment: Shake/vibrate was the first thing I thought of. Not so easy to accomplish in a web interface though. An alternative in the same vein would be to remove the original error message, show a "processing" spinner for half a second, then show the error message again. Just something to visually "refresh" the message.

Comment: @KoenLageveen Yes, it is a bit tricky to implement the vibrate in web (should not be too far ahead though). The spinner thing is a nice touch for the 2nd point though. Thanks!

Comment: For remove the password, I already do this. Do you really think it's sufficient by itself?

Comment: Should be sufficient enough. You can do a small test, get a small sample of representative users and have them test out if the visual que is good enough or not.

Comment: jQuery UI makes Shake/Bounce easy on a web interface.
See: http://jqueryui.com/effect/

Answer (score 3):

What I do is I remove the error as soon as the user changes the input to the password field. At that point, the attempted password has changed, so that error message no longer applies to that attempt. It's a new attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Combining red error text with a shake animation should be sufficient, this can be done easily with [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/). They have already implemented shake with css3 transitions. If you make it shake whenever password is wrong, the user should understand. You could also make the error text slide in (still using [animate.css](http://daneden.me/animate/)), giving another visual clue that the last action was wrong.

Another less intrusive approach is making the borders of the password input field glow red (or appear red). You don't need to remove the password, but instad focus the text (hinting that the user should delete and try again). When the user removes or edits the wrong password, clear the red border. This will make it appear that the user gets a new try, but if the user misses again the border should once again appear red. The red error text can be displayed through the whole process, but if you write "wrong username/password, try again", the user will be further lead to actually changing the input.

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow shows their error messages in some good ways (imagine it may be stack exchange in general).
When you don't meet requirements for number of characters changed when editing (or something similar), they put the message in a box below the input field. Then if you still don't meet the requirement on the next submit attempt, it moves it to the side of the input field as a floating box/Tooltip. Theirs also does shake a bit.

The processing spinner I think would be one of the best options. It'd be nice to have for your site in the event of slow server response anyways.
Every time an individual attempts to submit, show a *spinner* of some kind. While the spinner is going, I'd have the error messages removed from the DOM. If the password, etc is still incorrect, then you show the error message again and hide the spinner.

Comment: Welcome to UX.SE! Please take a look at the [faq](http://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) and [about](http://ux.stackexchange.com/about) pages to get a good idea on how to answer questions.

I'm not sure what you're referencing in your answer re: don't meet the requirements for number of edits. Can you explain that some more? What's the use-case for a processing spinner with an incorrect password?

Comment: Suppose I could've been more clear on that. When you try to edit someone else's answer, they require that you change at least 6 characters.